# Replacing outlier 2.5%, 97.5% code error in R

Tags: r, function, outliers, quantile

I used the following code to try to replace variables's value that are below the bottom 2.5% and above the top 97.5% with specific values.You can perform that code. It provides open data file.

```
credit<-read.csv("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv", header=TRUE)
fun <- function(x){
  quantiles <- quantile( x, c(.025, .975 ) )
  x[ x < quantiles[1] ] <- quantiles[1]
  x[ x > quantiles[2] ] <- quantiles[2]
  x
}
fun(credit)
```

But the error message is appeared.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

What's the problem? I happy to any help!

**+Addition comment**

I found that the above function does not work in the data frame but works only in the vector.

I can change the outlier of each variable in the data file with the following code:

```
credit$Duration.of.Credit..month. <- pmax(quantile(credit$Duration.of.Credit..month.,.025), 
                                          pmin(credit$Duration.of.Credit..month., quantile(credit$Duration.of.Credit..month.,.975)))
```

However, my data file has so many variables that it is inconvenient to enter code one by one.

So how can I change the outliers of the variables that a specific value not pmax&pmin?

Comment: The problem is that you have not selected any columns, as the error says.  `x` is the entire data frame.

Comment: @Rich Scriven 
Thanks for the reply. But I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain it in code?

Comment: `quantile( x, c(.025, .975 ) )` is the problem line.  Try it with `quantile( credit, c(.025, .975 ))`.  What column are you trying to run `quantile` on?  It only works on numeric vectors, not on entire data frames.

Comment: @RichScriven Oh. I got it. And I'm trying to run quantile as data frame. 
This is because the credit object is the data frame that stores the data... Then.. Is there anything I can do with a data frame?

Comment: If the column where you want to replace outliers is named `value`, you can do `credit$value <- pmax(quantile(credit$value,.025), pmin(credit$value, quantile(credit$value,.975)))`

Comment: @HubertL Thank you! But I have a lot of variables.... I want to apply that to all variables.... frustrated....  And in your code, how to change outlier value as specific value?? I want to change as specific value.

Comment: if you could `dput` a few rows/columns of your dataset, as well as expected result, it would be easiyer to help you

Answer (score 0):

There's actually nothing wrong with your function as long as you apply it to a column. I'd use `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` (if you really want to apply it to **all** columns) of the dplyr package. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
credit_trunc <- credit %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Credit.Amount, Creditability), funs(fun))
```

or

```
credit_trunc <- credit %>%
   mutate_all(funs(fun))
```

or if you also have columns of another type (e.g. factor, character) in your data frame, you can use:

```
 credit_trunc <- credit %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(fun))
```

This will give you back the data frame with the chosen / all columns / all numeric columns modified as you wanted it.

Comment: Did you check your code? If I use your code I got an error like that"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : factors are not allowed" Should i use only continuous value?

Comment: yeah i just ran it again. mh.. did you do something with the data between reading it in with read.csv and applying the function?

Comment: oh!!! I'm sorry.. 
My complete code also processed data in the form of factors. However, I think that an outlier can not existed for a factor type variable. Is that right?

Comment: yeah that doesn't really make sense for factors.

Comment: but if you also have variables of other types than numeric, you can also use `credit_trunc <- credit %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(fun))` . this only  applies the function to the variables which are numeric. maybe an alternative , given that you want to truncate **all** your numeric variables. i added that alternative to my solution.